# Form Contols in Outlook Interface

Tags: .net, winforms, outlook

I want to make an interface that looks like Outlook.  In the center pane, outlook contains a styled list that has multiple lines of formatted text and icons.  What control would I use to achieve this effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is totally googleable: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+outlook+style+listview+control